# Continuity of map $T: X \rightarrow X $

Tags: analysis, continuity

I have the following past exam question I've come across...

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed space. Show that the map T:X $\rightarrow X$ given by:

$$
 f_n(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   \dfrac{x}{||x||}
 &  x\not=0\\
   0      & x=0
  \end{cases}
$$

Is continuous at $x \not= 0 $, but not continous at $x=0$

The definition I have in my notes is let(X,d) and (y,d') be metric spaces and T:X$\rightarrow$ Y. 
T is continous at $x_0 \in x $ if for all $ \epsilon >0$ there exists $ \delta >0$ such that $d(x_0,x) < \delta \implies d'(Tx_0,Tx) <\epsilon$

I'm not sure how I use this to show the results in the question..

Answer (score 1):

So if it was continuous at 0, then for $\epsilon=\frac12$ we could find a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in X$ with $d(x,0) < \delta \implies d'(Tx,T(0))=d'(Tx,0) <\frac12$.
 
But here $d(x,y)=d'(x,y)=\|x-y\|, \forall x,y\in X$. So, for all $x\neq0$, $d'(Tx,0)=\|Tx\|=\left\|\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|=\dfrac{\|x\|}{\|x\|}=1$.

Do you see the problem?